# Cannot get option from select if position is set to absolute?

Tags: html, css

It appears than when I attempt to set my `phonebook`'s CSS `position` to `absolute`, I simply lock the `select` element. Relevant HTML/CSS below. When I remove the `position: absolute;` from the code, it runs perfectly fun; however, my HTML gets pushed down which is what I'm trying to avoid.

HTML

```
<div id="phonebook">
  <select id="catalog">
    <option value="u_none">None</option>
    <option value="u_1">John Doe (555-555-1254)</option>
    <option value="u_2">Jane Doe (555-555-2894)</option>
  </select>
  <div id="employee-info">
    <div id="employee-content">
      Role or Title<br>
      Full Name<br>
      Contact:<br>
      Telephone: 555-555-5555<br>
      Email: name.lastname@domain.com<br>
      Room: A-5555<br>
      Mail Stop: A-555
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#phonebook {
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#employee-info {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 0 none;
}

#employee-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

#catalog {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I've tried to play around with z-index -- at the suggestion of a somewhat unrelated post -- but it still seems to do me no good. I need this element in a specific portion and it relies heavily on using this dropdown `select` element.

Is there anyway to overcome this issue? I'm not exactly sure what is preventing my access to the `select` dropdown. An explanation would also be awesome.

Thanks ahead. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There must be more to it, because when I put your exact code into a snippet, it works fine. I see no difference with and without the `position: absolute;`

Please edit your question to put the code in a snippet (or jsfiddle) that shows the problem.

```css
#phonebook {
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#employee-info {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#employee-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
#catalog {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="phonebook">
  <select id="catalog">
    <option value="u_none">None</option>
    <option value="u_1">John Doe (555-555-1254)</option>
    <option value="u_2">Jane Doe (555-555-2894)</option>
  </select>
  <div id="employee-info">
    <div id="employee-content">
      Role or Title
      <br>Full Name
      <br>Contact:
      <br>Telephone: 555-555-5555
      <br>Email: name.lastname@domain.com
      <br>Room: A-5555
      <br>Mail Stop: A-555
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```